# Suppose that every vertex of G has degree at least 3. Prove that G has a cycle of even length.

Tags: graph-theory

Suppose that every vertex of G
has a degree at least 3. Prove that G
has a cycle of even length.

Comment: Welcome to Maths StackExchange.  Please include some of your thoughts in how you're going to prove this.  What does it mean to have a degree of at least 3?  What does it mean for a cycle of even length?  If you understand those ideas, I'm sure you'll figure out a proof.

Comment: I'll just note that since any finite graph $G$ of degree at least 2 has a cycle (this is easy to prove: think of a 2-regular finite graph), it suffices to prove that any graph with only odd cycles must have a vertex of degree 3.

Comment: @user1090793 Supposing you could prove "that any graph with only odd cycles must have a vertex of degree $3$" (which is false because the graph $C_5$ has only odd cycles and has no vertex of degree $3$) how would that help you solve the problem, which asks to prove that any graph with only odd cycles must have a vertex of degree LESS THAN $3$?

Comment: oh goodness, I meant to type "...must have a vertex of degree less than 3." Thank you for catching that!